# How to extract the parameter send in $http.get

Tags: angularjs, jax-rs

How to extract the parameter sent in angularjs $http.get request through ng-click event in rest service.

**controller:**

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller("myCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.checkName = function(input) {
    $http({
       method:'GET', 
       url:'http://localhost:8080/AngularWEB/rest/hello/name',
       params: {name: input}
    }).success(function (data) {
       $scope.getName = data;
    });
  }
});
```

**Rest Service:**

```
    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    @Path("/name")

    public Response getName(String name) {
        String output = "The Name is : " + name;
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }
```

name comes as null

Comment: why you are using get and sending param with it? you should append your params in url!

Comment: Is the Rest Service working properly? Try visiting http://localhost:8080/AngularWEB/rest/hello/name?name=myname in a browser

Comment: @Fortega. Yes its working. I am able to see "The Name is : " is getting printed.

Comment: @GauravSrivastava I am new to angularjs. The requirement is to send something from the screen to rest service. and get something back to display.